# Is there a free public outdoor gym somewhere in Dalat, Vietnam?

Tags: vietnam, activities, outdoor-activities, parks-and-gardens

I like to have a bit of a workout in those public gyms you find in parks in cities and towns around the world.

I especially like to find ones with chin-up bars, especially if one is high enough for a tallish westerner to use.

I found one in Saigon and I found one in the very first border town after I walked across from Cambodia to Vietnam.

But it's my eleventh day here in Dalat and I haven't found one despite lots of exploring. *But*, Dalat is a mountain town with all curvy windy streets so it's very easy to miss entire sections.

I also don't mind walking a few kilometres out from the centre.

Comment: It's been five months now, did you find something in your explorations of the area?

Comment: No I stayed there for almost one month and never found something. It's pretty labyrinthine though, so I could've still missed it.

Comment: That works for me.  If you made a *reasonable* attempt and came up empty, you would be qualified to give an authoritative answer.  You can add a disclaimer about 'labyrinthine' if you want, but for sure you can answer this question from an informed viewpoint.  People might be grateful for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently there is:
https://calisthenics-parks.com/spots/7582-en-da-lat-calisthenics-stations

Near the sports center.

Answer (score 4):

As per hippietrail's comment:

> No I stayed there for almost one month and never found something. It's pretty labyrinthine though, so I could've still missed it.

So we can presume a free outdoor gym is either non-existent or extremely hard to find. However there's a very cheap spa with a gym called "[Gym Spa Rosy Da Lat](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Gym-Spa-Rosy-%C4%90%C3%A0-L%E1%BA%A1t/1429317087353690?fref=ts)". As per [Tripadvisor reviews](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g293922-d7043551-r248206668-Rosy_Spa-Dalat_Lam_Dong_Province.html#or5), the price for a full day's stay is **50,000 VND** or ~**2.5 USD**.